# Yii Dynamic Listbox

Tags: php, yii

Currently in Yii I have an ajax call on a list box that on select will dynamically modify the next box. The ajax call currently points to my controller and method.

```
public function actionDynamicProducts()
    {
        foreach($_POST['ProductGroups']['id'] as $productGroups){
            $groupedP=GroupedProducts::model()->findAll('product_group_id=:product_group_id', array(':product_group_id'=>$productGroups));
            $groupedP=CHtml::listData($groupedP,'id','product_id');
            foreach($groupedP as $value=>$product_id){
                $data=Products::model()->findAll('id=:id', array(':id'=>$product_id));
                $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','title');
                foreach($data as $value=>$title){
                    echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($title),true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Currently it works perfectly fine but what I would like for it to do is the reverse where if a group is selected the next box does not show the products related to it. I tried `$data=Products::model()->findAll('id!=:id', array(':id'=>$product_id));` but if multiple items are selected it will just display whats not available. For example

```
$Products  =  
    Array (
          0 => Ties
          1 => Shirts
          2 => Jeans
    )

$groupProducts =
    Array (
          0 => Shirts and Jeans
          1 => Ties
          2 => Jeans and Ties
    )
```

If I select Shirts and Jeans, I would like just Ties to show. Or if I select Shirts and Jeans, Ties nothing should show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in your logic. Every iteration of your first 'foreach' generates a set of option tags.
Example:

1. you select: Shirts and Jeans, Ties.
2. the first iteration of external foreach gets 'Shirts and Jeans' product group and displays Ties option.
3. the second iteration of external foreach gets 'Ties' product group and displays Shirts and Jeans options.

So to fix it you can do smth like that:

```
// condition whith not in param
$dbc = new CDBCriteria();
$dbc->addNotInCondition('product_group_id', $_POST['ProductGroups']['id']);
$groupedP=GroupedProducts::model()->findAll($dbc);
$groupedP=CHtml::listData($groupedP,'id','product_id');
foreach($groupedP as $value=>$product_id){
    $data=Products::model()->findAll('id=:id', array(':id'=>$product_id));
    $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','title');
    foreach($data as $value=>$title){
        echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($title),true);
    }
}
```

Hope, it will help you.